# Is there any option to download souce code from uploaded apk from our developer account?

Tags: android, google-play, recovery

i have develope one project,it is completed and succesfully upload on google play,but i have made some changes according to clients requirement,i dont have any back up from last 15 days,unfortunatly my project crashed and all files become 0 byte,(blank),also from history not able to recover,is there any way to recover.
Plese help....

Answer (score 0):

Ouch.  You can decompile your APK using something like [this](http://www.decompileandroid.com/), but the resulting source will require a lot of manual work to get it compiling again, comments will be lost, constants will be inlined, etc.  More importantly, there's no way to recover your signing key if you lost it.  If you recreate the app with a new key, it will be a different app as far as the Play Store is concerned.

Next time, use version control and make backups...